event.targetTouches generates javascript error on some browsers
I’ve built a custom carousel with momentum and all works fine on my own browsers. However, Sentry gives me the following error “Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘0’)” for some Windows browsers, referring to my line of code: event.targetTouches[0].pageX.
Since not all browsers support targetTouches, I added a condition if’(TouchEvent’ in window), but still the same error message appears.
Does anybody know a method to receive the mouse/touch position which works for all browsers (or with proper error handling for browsers that don’t support)
My current code to detect mouse-position:
function getSwipeMousePosition(event) {
    if ('TouchEvent' in window) return {
       'x': event.pageX || event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
       'y': event.pageY || event.targetTouches[0].pageY
    };
}

In case it helps, my full code can be found at takeyourbackpack.com (search for getSwipeMousePosition)

Have you tried using Pointer events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events — then you don't need to worry about the difference in mouse vs. touch.

Also, an obvious critique about naming your function getSwipeMousePosition. Also, I would consider using myElement.getBoundingClientRect() with Event.clientX(Y) instead of using pageX(Y) - if it's easier/viable for your logic to be relative to the viewport instead of document coordinates.

Also, if you decide to use Pointer events, don't forget to take a look at setPointerCapture and releasePointerCapture

Also, typo... ‘x’: should be 'x': or just x:

Thanks @RokoC.Buljan, I will have a look at Pointer events. And the typo was just here, not in my original code.

Instead of inferring that targetTouches exist as soon as a TouchEvent constructor is available in the window, simply check for the existence of the property:
function getSwipeMousePosition(event) {
  if (event.targetTouches && event.targetTouches[0])  {
    // only executed when the .targetTouches property exists and has an entry
    return {
      x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
      y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY
    };
  }
  return {
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY
  };
}


isn't that kind of the same as "event.pageX || event.targetTouches[0].pageX"? Since targetTouches is only evaluated when pageX doesn't exist, right?

It's not :) Your code infers that event.targetTouches exist when 'TouchEvent' in window returns true, my answer instead checks if event.targetTouches exist on the the event object - that's the main difference. Also, event.pageX || ... will select event.targetTouches[0] even if event.pageX exist but has a value of 0 since 0 in a logical OR is interpreted as false.

got it! Thanks. I changed the function now into function getPointerPosition(event) {                 let e = (event.touches && event.touches[0]) ? event.touches[0] : event;                 return {'x': e.pageX, 'y': e.pageY, 'yScreen': e.screenY}; }

Just use Pointer Events...
